# Merging Only Selected Lines in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, merge

Working in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop, is there a way to only merge selected lines from a layer?

For example, I want to merge these three red lines (all from one layer).

[image]

Comment: start an edit session, make the layer the only selectable layer. select the 3 lines, go to edit toolbar dropdown. Merge. It is on the selected lines only.  Also the arctool will work on the selected set. but works slightly different from the edit pulldown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add visuals for @  Brad Nesom --

> start an edit session, make the layer the only selectable layer.
>   select the 3 lines, go to edit toolbar dropdown. Merge. It is on the
>   selected lines only. Also the arctool will work on the selected set.
>   but works slightly different from the edit pulldown. - Brad Nesom

[image: Merge]

Comment: Please Edit you question to add additional information, this does not look like it answers your question, but you are supplying more information.